# Capture Signature using HTML5 and iPad

Tags: ipad, html, canvas, svg

Anyone know how this can be done? Would you use a canvas object, svg, jQuery, etc?

Comment: See demo https://codepen.io/yguo/pen/OyYGxQ

Answer (score 351, accepted):

Here's another canvas based version with variable width (based on drawing velocity) curves: demo at http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad and code at https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad.

[image: signature sample]

Comment: Thanks in advance, best js signature lib I ever seen. Don't know why this answer just had 3 votes. https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

Comment: I like that this does not rely on other js libraries and how well it looks.  One note about using it which helped me: add a border to the canvas so you can see how it is being adjusted.  Also note that css changes to the canvas do some crazy things, so just specify a height and width in the canvas element if this get out of control.

Comment: Lack of documentation isn't helpful, but the demo page lays it all out pretty clearly. I am working on storing it in the database and retrieving. This is a REALLY slick library. Thanks szimek!

Comment: Jake, what exactly is missing in your opinion in the documentation provided in README file? I'm open to suggestions how to improve it.

Comment: I apologize. I think your documentation is actually adequate. It seemed limited until I realized just how easy this is to use. I got it fully implemented in a form, storing in the database and retrieving back to page in under an hour. I suppose, I was comparing it to libraries that were much more complex to use like the chosen answer above. I hadn't worked with data URIs before, but it is a truly brilliant way to handle the storage of the data. So, I just had to acclimate myself to those and then storing and retrieving in the database was so... easy... wow. Thanks again!

Comment: No need to apologize :) I'm glad you like it. I'll probably add some info or at least a link to the wiki page about handling data URIs on the server side. Cheers!

Comment: szimek, your signature pad library works wonderfully, was exactly what I was looking for and is very easy to use. Thank you!

Comment: i was not able to somehow disable scroll for ios somehow but this plugin works like charm! Recomended

Comment: I'm having a few problems with the signature pad plugin, I think it's mainly due to the fact I've removed all the absolute positioning (the signature pad is part of a page, not a page on it's own like in the demo). Been hacking away but it's quite frustrating.

Comment: @martincarlin87 Are you talking about desktop or mobile?

Comment: @szimek Just testing on desktop for now. Couldn't get it to work for some reason.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to accept this answer. I abandoned the project a few years ago.

Comment: @szimek I need 2 signatures in a same page, how do I do it?

Comment: @szimek How to change pen color to red?

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding check out the README file - there's a list of all possible options. The one you're looking for is called "penColor".

Comment: @szimek Thank you very much for a wonderful plugin and an intuitive support!

Answer (score 62):

A canvas element with some JavaScript would work great.

In fact, [Signature Pad](https://github.com/thread-pond/signature-pad/blob/master/documentation.md) (a jQuery plugin) already has this implemented.

Comment: I am astonished how beautiful this plugin is.

Comment: I found this plugin really hard to use unforutnately. All the demos were very specific and tricky to apply. Definitely like the other signature pad approach better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17200715/76672 With pretty much no documentation, I was able to get it working...

Answer (score 20):

Here is [a quickly hacked up version of this using SVG](http://mcc.id.au/2010/signature.html) I just did.  Works well for me on my iPhone.  Also works in a desktop browser using normal mouse events.

Comment: I want to know how draw a saved signature

Comment: How to save signature as png file or show signature in in other way ?

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps the best two browser techs for this are Canvas, with Flash as a back up.

We tried VML on IE as backup for Canvas, but it was much slower than Flash. SVG was slower then all the rest.

With jSignature ( http://willowsystems.github.com/jSignature/ ) we used Canvas as primary, with fallback to Flash-based Canvas emulator (FlashCanvas) for IE8 and less. Id' say worked very well for us.

Comment: This is really nice... I like it's smoothing effects. Best I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

The options already listed are very good, however here a few more on this topic that I've researched and came across.

    1) http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/
    2) http://mcc.id.au/2010/signature.html
    3) https://zipso.net/a-simple-touchscreen-sketchpad-using-javascript-and-html5/

And as always you may want to save the canvas to image:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/

good luck and happy signing

Answer (score 2):

@szimek (selected answer) has a well-documented solution for those who want a full-featured module with a MIT license that's good-to-go. @heycam has a simpler solution that requires no libraries or plugins, has no licenses, and can be easily customized; all of which makes it a better fit for my needs. This post tries to explain how exactly his solution works.

Basic workflow:

1. Create a functionally blank `svg` to contain the signature
2. Reserve a `path` element inside the container `svg`
3. Use touch events (`touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`) for the user to draw the signature using touch inputs
4. Use mouse events (`mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseup`, `mouseout`) for the user to draw the signature using mouse inputs
5. On each event, detect the type of input (touch, mouse) to get the X,Y coordinates of the path the user is drawing
6. Append each path to the `d` attribute (path coordinates) of the `path` element so it displays to the user
7. Add a helper function to output the signature path (`path.d`), which is just a `string` you can plug back into the `path.d` later on to restore the signature
8. Add a helper function to clear the `path.d` value

Here's @heycam's solution as a runnable snippet:

```js
//init
let r = document.getElementById('r'),
  p = document.getElementById('p'),
  signaturePath = '',
  isDown = false,
  svg = document.getElementById('sig_panel'),
  b_show = document.getElementById('show'),
  b_clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
  pathdata = document.getElementById('pathdata');

//drawing functions
function isTouchEvent(e) {
  return e.type.match(/^touch/);
}

function getCoords(e) {
  if (isTouchEvent(e)) {
    return e.targetTouches[0].clientX + ',' + e.targetTouches[0].clientY;
  }
  return e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY;
}

function down(e) {
  signaturePath += 'M' + getCoords(e) + ' ';
  p.setAttribute('d', signaturePath);
  isDown = true;

  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
}

function move(e) {
  if (isDown) {
    signaturePath += 'L' + getCoords(e) + ' ';
    p.setAttribute('d', signaturePath);
  }

  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
}

function up(e) {
  isDown = false;

  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
}

//input handlers
r.addEventListener('touchstart', down, false);
r.addEventListener('touchmove', move, false);
r.addEventListener('touchend', up, false);
r.addEventListener('mousedown', down, false);
r.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
r.addEventListener('mouseup', up, false);
r.addEventListener('mouseout', up, false);

//helper functions
function clearSignature() {
  pathdata.textContent = '';
  signaturePath = '';
  p.setAttribute('d', '');
}

function getSignature() {
  pathdata.textContent = signaturePath;
  return signaturePath;
}

//button handlers
b_show.addEventListener('click', getSignature);
b_clear.addEventListener('click', clearSignature);
```

```css
svg {
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: .5em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  margin: .5em;
}

#pathdata {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em .5em;
}
```

```html
<svg id="sig_panel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <rect id="r" width="300" height="100" fill="#ffa"/>
  <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="300" y2="80" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3" shape-rendering="crispEdges" pointer-events="none"/>
  <path id="p" stroke="navy" stroke-width="2" fill="none" pointer-events="none"/>
</svg>
<div class="flex">
  <button id="show">Show signaure path data</button>
  <button id="clear">Clear signature</button>
</div>
<div id="pathdata"></div>
```

Saving the `path.d` value on the server (and client cache) is all I need. Others may need to save the entire `svg` itself with `path.d` filled in, or convert it to other formats (JPEG, PNG, PDF) using appropriate converters (not covered here).

I plan to go a step beyond and add user controls to manage the following:

- line thickness: `path.stroke-width`
- line color: `path.stroke`
- line quality: `path.shape-rendering`

and theme the signature field (as part of my custom form lib):

- container dimensions: `rect.width`, `rect.height`
- container background: `rect.fill`
- eliminate the "sign here" line: `line`

Answer (score 0):

Another OpenSource signature field is https://github.com/applicius/jquery.signfield/ , registered jQuery plugin using Sketch.js .