# How can I collect signatures from site visitors?

Tags: php, jquery, image

How would I go about collecting a signature from a site visitor?

I am building my site in PHP and would like to give the user the ability to add their signature to a form. They can use their mouse to draw the signature. The signature would be compressed and added to the rest of the form data using the GD library (if possible).

I am open to using Flash, jQuery, or PHP, but I’m not sure where to start.

Comment: Just a note - you don't necessarily need a physical signature from someone to make it legitimate. See [wikipedia/electronic_signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_signature)

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to do this with a third party service like [DocuSign](http://www.docusign.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at [Capture Signature using HTML5 and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096470/capture-signature-using-html5-and-ipad).  The solution proposed by heycam (with a demo) uses SVG to capture the signature.  This svg path is ASCII so it's very easy to manipulate and store without losing precision or quality.

Comment: Great I will take a look at the link and demo. +1